# Wrong caller ID for home number

Tags: contacts, calls, 4.4-kitkat, google-contacts, people-app

I recently had to wipe my Nexus 4 in order to root it.

Prior to that when I received a call from my home telephone it would display my wife's contact from the caller ID.

Since rooting it now displays my own contact instead.

My contacts are synced from my Google account and I haven't changed anything on my Google account.

The only thing that has changed is the wipe and root.

How can I get it to display my wife's contact again?

Answer (score 1):

You could always remove the home number from your contact information. It will then match your wife when getting a call from home. You can try re-adding the home number back to your own contact card and see if the change sticks.

If you have the home number in your own contact info as well as your wife's, Android will display the first contact it finds. Since your 'self' card was probably synced before your wife's card, Android shows your 'self' card as the incoming contact. (Whereas before, you likely added the home number to your wife's contact first, then to your 'self' card later).

There's another android.se question asking a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14069/how-can-i-set-a-default-contact-for-a-phone-number).

Comment: Ah, interesting thought - is it alphabetical order or order of being added to the phone? I'll do some testing. Thanks!